# Where to hear live rendition of the National anthem in NYC?

Tags: usa, new-york-city

What sort of events play live renditions of the Star Spangled Banner, that are preferably free for public? Sports events come to mind, but it is beginning to be late to get good tickets for cheap.

We are staying in NYC for a week in late September.

Comment: This is surprisingly difficult to google about.

Comment: While *The Star-Spangled Banner* has a [long history with baseball](http://espn.go.com/espn/story/_/id/6957582/the-history-national-anthem-sports-espn-magazine), it has become customary to sing it before almost every major spectator sports event, certainly at the professional and collegiate levels— though [not always](http://www.goshen.edu/anthem/background/), and [not without controversy](http://www.theblaze.com/stories/2013/11/06/espn-panelist-and-prof-unloads-on-war-anthem-being-played-before-sporting-events-and-says-nfl-has-bought-into-mythology-of-popular-fallen-soldier/).

Comment: I have to ask... Why?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: I like live music and I love America. (I'm a foreigner so I can say that ;-)

Comment: public - zero.  paid - literally any sports game.

Comment: High school sporting events are sometimes (but hardly always) free. Although the game (and the musical performance) quality is roughly in line with the admission price, too.

Comment: I agree with LessPop_MoreFizz. Why on earth would you care to hear it. Our National Anthem is one of the more difficult to sing songs there is, or so I'm told by those who've tried, and it tends to sound like it.

Comment: Do a google search for "High School Football in New York City" and send emails out to all you find. Ask them how far they are from wherever you are planning to stay, ask if any of their games will have live renditions.

Comment: @CGCampbell: It's a famous song, sung practically religiously by a famously patriotic country. I can see the appeal of a foreign visitor. It's not about the art of the music, it's about experiencing part of the American culture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said, sporting events are usually your best bet for a guaranteed National Anthem. While they (usually) aren't free, if you're not picky about your sport, there's probably more than a few that you can get for relatively cheap.

Soccer (football) is in mid-season right now so tickets probably aren't that expensive and I know that there're at least two teams in the area ([New York Red Bulls](http://www.newyorkredbulls.com) and [New York Cosmos](http://www.nycosmos.com)).

You can also check out minor league baseball, but that will be over by the end of September.

Preseason tickets for any sport are also usually cheap. I noticed that the [New York Rangers](http://rangers.nhl.com) and [New York Islanders](http://islanders.nhl.com) will be playing that week. Basketball doesn't start until October.

Major League Baseball can be very hit or miss as far as ticket prices go at that time of year. There are almost aways some very cheap tickets available if you're willing to sit in bad seats, but that's up to you.

Beyond the professional ranks, you can always check out some younger teams. For instance, a high school football game will also play the National Anthem before the game. That's starting to get pretty far down the list of places you probably want to end up just to hear something you can get on your phone for less than $1.

Comment: Keep in mind that many (most?) professional sporting events will use a pre-recorded instrumental national anthem, usually, but not always, with a live singer of varying quality.

Comment: Soccer is a good idea. The idea is to hear it rendered live so any music/app purchase kind of doesn't cut it.